# Getting status code 403 when working with Tweepy search API

Tags: python-3.x, api, list-comprehension, tweepy

I am trying to get the tweets in a 10 miles radius around Twitter's headquarters in San Francisco location using Tweepy API. I have authenitication information (api key, etc.) in an external .json file.

Below is my code:

```
import tweepy as tw
import json
import pandas as pd
import datetime

secrets = json.loads(open('secrets.json').read())
api_key = secrets['api_key']
api_secret_key = secrets['api_secret_key']
access_token = secrets['access_token']
access_token_secret = secrets['access_token_secret']

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth) 

try: 
   api.verify_credentials()
   print('Authenticated')
except:
   print("Error authenticating")

 # After running the above, I get status 'Authenitcated'

 start = '2020-09-01'
 end = '2020-09-26'
 location = '37.7749, 122.4149, 10miles'
 query = "*"
 max_tweets = 1000

 tweet_search_results = [status for status in tw.Cursor(api.search, query=query, geocode=location, since=start, until=end).items(max_tweets)]
```

After running the above, I get this error:

```
TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 403
```

This status code means access to the requested resource is forbidden for some reason. The server understood the request, but will not fulfill due to the client-related issues.

Within the same code I am able to get the list of tweets for a specific user name, but without geolocation data.

Why am I getting 403 when trying to get geolocation tweets?